# Что такое трехмерный вектор и сколько в нем должно быть компонентов?

Tags: математика, геометрия

Геометрический трехмерный вектор характеризуется **двумя** упорядоченными трехмерными **точками** - начало вектора и конец вектора. **Каждая** точка характеризуется тремя числами (x, y, z). Я правильно помню, не ошибаюсь? То есть, для представляения трехмерного вектора потребуется шесть чисел, а лучше два типа Point3D, каждый содержащий по три числа.

Почему в книге "Изучай Хаскелл во имя добра" автор представляет тип вектора только через три числа? Кто из нас чего-то не понимает?

```
data Vector a = Vector a a a deriving (Show)
```

Вот ссылка:
http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses

Comment: "трехмерный вектор характеризуется двумя трехмерными точками" - нет.

Comment: @Igor упорядоченными

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что вектор между точками (1,2,3) и (4,5,6) отличается от вектора между точками (7,8,9) и (10,11,12)?...

Comment: смотря что считать за эквивалентность

Comment: Эквивалентность у векторов одна - длина и направление...

Comment: *Математика - область точных определений.*

Comment: Возможно принять математическую теорию, в которой определить эквивалентость векторов (всего лишь направленных отрезков) за полное совпадение их в пространстве. Математика ведь не библия, в ней нет абсолютных истин, верна каждая непротиворечивая теория

Comment: Вижу, что попал в клуб, где девиз - "Когда мне понадобится математика, я ее выучу."

Comment: Поиск слова [Вектор](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:ru:unofficial) в Гугле сразу выбрасывает: *Изображаемая отрезком прямой математическая величина, характеризующаяся численным значением и направлением*. Я бы еще понял, если бы вы хоть раз произнесли "*фиксированный вектор*", но вы так и не догадались этого сделать :) Вот для **фиксированного вектора** действительно нужны обе точки...

Comment: так и есть, глубоко эти области не знаю, больше сконцентрирован на логике, лямбда исчислении, где без евклидовой геометрии можно обойтись. С другой стороны кто подробно знает ВСЕ области математики, пусть первым бросит в меня камень. По поводу векторов запомнил определение из школьного курса физики, про приложение силы и правило параллелограмма

Comment: Тем более, уж в школе-то (и в математике. и в физике) рассматриваются только свободные вектора, характеризующиеся длиной и направлением. Сами подумайте - для фиксированных векторов искать сумму параллелограммом никак нельзя - потому что этот способ как раз и основан на том, что вектор после параллельного переноса эквивалентен исходному!

Comment: Ну что сказать, посрамлен ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Подразумевается [радиус-вектор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%83%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80), т.е. вектор, отложенный от начала координат (от точки `(0,0,0)`), и haskell тут ни при чем.

Comment: Аааааааааааааа!

Comment: Хаскелл в метках только потому, что книга и пример на хаскелле

Comment: Вы бы хоть пометили, что это дело радиус-вектором зовётся, а то может возникнуть закономерный вопрос: `а почему именно (0, 0, 0)?`

Comment: @Kir_Antipov спасибо за комментарий, сейчас добавлю ссылку в ответ

Answer (score 4):

Парой упорядоченных точек описывается *направленный отрезок*, а не вектор.

*Вектор* в математике - концепция, обладающая направлением и величиной (амплитудой, длиной), но не обладающая никаким конкретным положением в пространстве. Вектор никогда ни от чего не "отложен". Для задания вектора достаточно одной точки `P` в пространстве. Его величина равна длине отрезка `OP`, а направление совпадает с направлением направленного отрезка `OP` (где `O` - начало координат). Это однако никоим образом не означает, что вектор каким-то образом "привязан" к точке `O`.

Вектор можно эквивалентным образом однозначно задать и как явно указанное направление (например, через углы к осям координат) и явно заданную длину. Такой вариант задания очевидным образом не будет привязан ни к какой точке пространства. В повседневной жизни мы обычно пользуемся именно этим способом описания двумерных векторных величин ("автомобиль едет на север со скоростью 50 км/ч"). Но в математике задание через точку является более униформным и "осязаемым" в многомерных случаях.

Вектор можно рассматривать как эквивалент *множества* всевозможных направленных отрезков одной длины и одного направления. *Направленные отрезки* `(0, 0)-(1, 1)` и `(0, -2)-(1, -1)` соответствуют одному и тому же *вектору*.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, буду знать. Запомнилось определение вектора из школьной физики, для расчетов приложения силы по правилу параллелограмма

Comment: Добавьте к слову "вектор" слово "свободный" для полного формализма определения :)

Comment: @Harry: Как раз наоборот. В терминологии, различающей *векторы* и *направленные отрезки*, не нужны никакие "свободные векторы". Вектор - это вектор, как описано выше. Он не бывает "свободным" или "не свободным". Деление на "свободные" и какие-либо другие векторы - это специализированный слэнг.

Comment: "Все уже успокоились, а Паша Эмильевич все еще бродил по комнатам, заглядывал под графины, передвигал чайные жестяные кружки и бормотал:"

Comment: Про математику: Мне надо кому-нибудь поставить минус, чтобы репутация стала красивым числом.

Comment: @asianirish: Использование векторов в физике как раз и призвано подчеркнуть инвариантность физических законов по отношению к положению в пространстве. Включая правило параллелограмма.

Answer (score 2):

Другие три числа это (0, 0, 0).